# How to handle collisions in a game?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision, computational-physics, software

This must seem like a very basic question, but I'm building a game engine and need some help. Let's say that two objects, **o1** and **o2** collide with each other (defined by the first time their bounds overlap).

A collision event is fired, and I have to implement Newton's second law of reaction.

What I have:

- The location of each object (x, y, z)
- The vector of each object (x, y, z)
- The mass of each object
- Functions to calculate kinetic energy in Joules

What I have to do:

- Apply changes to the vector of each object using the variables

What I've tried:

- Simply modifying each object's vector by -1 (this somehow resulted in the object jumping back higher than it started; I already have gravity in place)
- Adding the ratio of each object's mass (m1 / m2 for o1) to the factor of -1 (this completely stopped the movement of an object when it collided with the ground, which has infinite mass)

I understand that the amount of acceleration on collision is proportional to the objects' kinetic energy, but I have no idea on how to apply this kinetic energy to the vector of each object.

Here's what i have so far:

```
@Override
public void handle(@Nonnull CollisionEvent event) {
    final TObject o1 = event.getObject1();
    final TObject o2 = event.getObject2();

    final double e1 = Physics.kineticEnergy(o1);
    final double e2 = Physics.kineticEnergy(o2);
}
```

Comment: What about conservation of momentum?

Comment: @KyleKanos That was my thought process when I tried simply reversing their vectors. My understanding of physics isn't very deep, but shouldn't lighter objects bounce off more than heavier ones?

Comment: Realistic collisions in 2D and 3D are actually not trivial if I'm not mistaken. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211114/2d-elastic-ball-collision-physics/35212639#35212639) gives the formulas in the case of elastic collisions between two round objects in 2D (see **Physics law to use** for the assumptions used to derive the formula), but I assume you would want/need something more general.

Comment: @MaximalIdeal I'm really new to physics notations, does v mean velocity or vector?

Comment: @LXIV I'm just curious, what do you define as vector?

Comment: @MaximalIdeal My vector has an x, y, z which each represent m/s2 in horizontal, vertical, and depth. It's applied every tick to an object's location adjusted to the duration it took between now and the most recent tick. Simple movement and gravity works like a charm.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There really can't be a straight forward solution unless you assume that the collisions are between spheres. Think of how two cubes would react differently than two spheres when colliding.

Comment: @MaxW Aren't they similar enough to just process collisions as spheres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the one-dimensional case, if two objects with masses $m_1, m_2$ and velocities $u_1, u_2$ collide *and* the collision is perfectly elastic (i.e. no energy is "lost" to the environment) then the velocities of the objects after the collision will be $v_1, v_2$ given by

$\displaystyle v_1 = \frac{m_1-m_2}{m_1+m_2}u_1 + \frac{2m_2}{m_1+m_2}u_2
\\ \displaystyle v_2 = \frac{2m_1}{m_1+m_2}u_1 + \frac{m_2-m_1}{m_1+m_2}u_2$

- see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision).

As pointed out in the comments, you can only generalise this easily to the three-dimensional case if all of your moving objects are spheres. If they are not then collisions become much more complicated, since the objects can rotate at different rates before and after the collision.

Even if all your moving objects are spheres, you may find that perfectly elastic collisions look unrealistic - a bouncing ball will keep returning to the same height and will bounce forever, for example. So you might want to introduce some degree of inelasticity - see [coefficient of restitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I kept looking at the linear quadratic and was wondering how to solve it. I solved the issue of elasticity by introducing air resistance, and by not applying gravity to objects standing on immovable objects.